# Is there a word that describes an inept schemer?

Tags: single-word-requests, pejorative-language

I am idly curious as to whether there is a word for someone who is prone to scheming, but not terribly good at it.

Comment: That would be Blackadder's [Baldrick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baldrick), who invariably [has a cunning plan](https://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&source=hp&q=%22I+have+a+cunning+plan%22&aq=f&aqi=g5g-z1g4&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=) (that actually ***isn't!*** :)

Comment: Perhaps a "bungler"?

Comment: [*The Gang Who Couldn't Shoot Straight*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Gang_That_Couldn't_Shoot_Straight)? Not quite schemers, but bunglers nevertheless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The phrase **[hoisted on his own petard](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/british/be-hoist-ed-with-by-your-own-petard)** conveys the concept

> to suffer harm from a plan by which you had intended to harm someone else

The phrase is used by [Shakespeare](http://www.shakespeareforalltime.com/hoist-with-his-own-petard/) in Hamlet

> *For ’tis the sport to have the engineer*
>
> *Hoist with his own petard*

An *engineer* is a builder of military equipment, and a *petard* is a type of bomb to blow a hole in a wall. In effect,

> *it's amusing to see the would be bomb-builder blow himself up.*

The Warner Bros. cartoon character, [Wile E.Coyote](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wile_E._Coyote_and_The_Road_Runner), is an embodiment of the concept, scheming to destroy his nemesis, The Roadrunner, but constantly being defeated (and injured in grandiose fashion) by his own conniving.